# Including smarty in javascript

Tags: smarty

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cutValue = plgShirt.getValueCut();
    {limiter}$cutValue{/limiter} = cutValue;
</script>
```

I want to assign a smarty variable to a java script variable that can help me.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var cutValue = 1;
  var {$cutValue} = cutValue;
  for(let b in window) { 
    if(window.hasOwnProperty(b)) console.log(b); 
  }
</script>
```